# Hosting node pools in a different subscription than the control plane?

Tags: azure-aks

We received a subscription with additional credits from Microsoft through the Microsoft Partner program.

Now we'd like to use it and reduce operational costs by hosting our AKS node pools in that subscription.

However, it seems moving an existing aks Cluster/node pool isn't supported. Also, I couldn't find anything in the azure CLI documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-movemigrate-my-cluster-between-azure-tenants

Any idea?

Comment: The nodepool is nothing but one or more VMs or VM scaleset based on your configuration, which you can find under `MC_<your-RG>_<your-cluster>_<location>` resource group. Have you tried to migrate it to new subscription? If scaleset, it may not be currently possible. Please review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/virtual-machines-move-limitations?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-movemigrate-my-cluster-between-azure-tenants